# how practical the number of cores in Android

Tags: kernel, cpu, android

I've often wondered how practical the cores usage in Android smartphone. I'm asking here because Android is based on Linux.

I'm looking from technical perspective. The articles that I've read so far claimed either more cores is good for multitasking or more cores is a waste because many applications are not optimized for more that 1 core usage.

Regarding the latter one, is not CPU resource allocated by kernel? Is not the optimization the kernel's responsibility instead of the applications (process)?

Comment: The kernel doesn't really have time to critique the instructions contained in the binaries it runs. The SDK and the compiler are already working hard to optimise a developer's code, not to mention that nowadays, IDEs can fight a developer's absent-mindedness before they even compile their code. Besides, on Android, the virtual machine gets in the game before the kernel really does...